# how to show genres through associatin in the song controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if you go to www.leapfm.com you'll see each song has a youtube url in parenthesis to the right of it. After gauging feedback I have decided to instead display the genre tags in the parenthesis.

When trying to do this,

**I'm getting this error:**

```
Couldn't find Genre without an ID
Extracted source:

def genre_name
@genre = Genre.find(params[:id])
end
def get_last_song
```

**song_controller snippit**

```
def index
      if params[:query].present? 
      @songs = Song.search(params)
      get_last_song
      genre_name
    elsif params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
      genre_name
    else      
      @songs = Song.order('id').order('plusminus desc nulls last').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15) 
      #@songs = Song.tally.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
      genre_name
    end
  end

  def genre_name
    @genre = Genre.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**index.html.erb (_song partial) snippit**

```
<div class="title">
  <%=link_to image_tag('arrow.gif'), vote_for_song_path(song), :remote => true, :method => :put  if controller.action_name == "index" %>
  <%= link_to song.title, song %><span class="subtext"> (<%= song.genre_name %>)</span>
</div>
```

**song.rb snippit:**

**class Song < ActiveRecord::Base**

```
acts_as_voteable

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :genre_songs
  has_many :genres, through: :genre_songs
```

**genre.rb**

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genre_songs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :songs, through: :genre_songs

end
```

**schema snippit**

```
 create_table "genre_songs", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "genre_id"
    t.integer  "song_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "genre_songs", ["genre_id"], name: "index_genre_songs_on_genre_id", using: :btree
  add_index "genre_songs", ["song_id"], name: "index_genre_songs_on_song_id", using: :btree

  create_table "genres", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "songs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "artist"
    t.text     "url"
    t.string   "track_file_name"
    t.string   "track_content_type"
    t.integer  "track_file_size"
    t.datetime "track_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "plusminus"
  end
```

Comment: Could you give more details about how your models are related? I.e. does Song has_many :genres? What are the params passed to action, especially is id passed id of a song or id of a genre?

Comment: I've updated initial post :)

Comment: Ok, the key point is that params[:id] is not specified. As in most cases you are displaying many songs, which genre do you want to use? I believe you just want to display each song genre just next to it. If so, the method genre_name has no sense - instead you should use @song.genres in your view. Could you just confirm that's what you want, and I will write the whole answer

Comment: if you go to the website you'll see that each song has it's own genre(s). So yes i'd like to dynamically display the specific genre(s) for each song in the parentheses. song.genres returns ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Genre:0x007fcde2080d10>

Comment: @Apane101 you had this code in show.html.erb, `<%= raw @song.genres.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, genre_path(t) }.join(', ') %>` and this what you had to use in `_song.html.erb` too. Only instead of `@song` you'll have `song` variable. This will give you genres and link to each genre to filter songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid off gendre_name method, as it doesn't give you what you want. You've assigned @songs to some list of songs, hence most likely somewhere in your view you have sth like:

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
   # display song row
<% end %>
```

if so, use sth like below inside this each "loop":

```
(<%= song.genres.map(&:names).join(', ') %>)
```